# How to efficiently build a sentence-level inverted index?

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, search

I am trying to build a sentence-level inverted index based on a document-level inverted index. What I have is a document-level inverted index like these:

```
'aaa': [doc1, doc2, doc3]
'bbb': [doc1, doc3]
'ccc': [doc2]
......
```

and a set of documents with full texts like these:

```
doc1: ['this is a sentence containing aaa.', 'sentence containing bbb.', 'other sentence']
doc2: ['other sentence', 'sentence containing aaa', 'ccc']
doc3: ['aaa', 'bbb']
......
```

My desired sentence-level inverted index is:

```
'aaa': [doc1-sent0, doc2-sent1, doc3-sent0]
'bbb': [doc1-sent1, doc3-sent1]
'ccc': [doc2-sent2]
.......
```

First, I query all related words of a document, take `doc1` as an example:

```
doc1: ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

Then, I iterate each sentence for each document using regex expression:

```
for doc in documents:
    result = {}
    for i, sent in enuermate(doc.sentences):
        s = re.search('|'.join(related_word_list), sent)
        if s is not None:
            result[i] = s.group(0)
```

This code works fine but it is extremely slow (~3 seconds per document, the documents are scientific literature with 8~9K words on average). Can I do it in a faster way? It would be nice to achieve the speed at ~10 documents per second.

I haven't used multiprocessing, but can I enhance the performance without it?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not storing `(doc, sentence_offsets)` within the document level inverted index?

For instance, `"aaa": { "doc1": [0], "doc2": [1], "doc3": [0]}`

Comment: maybe can you share a reproducible example with 1 doc and the words you want to find. (this would allow comparing solutions before proposal). I would hint that tokenizing + iterating the tokens (and with its starting character index) against the dictionary takes less than 3s. Finding in which sentence the matched token belongs can be done in a dichotomic fashion if lazy or along the iteration if we advance the sentence according to the character index of the token

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Because the doc level index isn't created by me, I am trying to enhance it.

Comment: @TomLeung If you're not allowed to modify it, how about storing the mapping I suggested as a seperate entity?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Yeah, I am trying to achieve this but it is very slow. Still trying the method suggested by grodzi.